# Obj-C, Receiver in message expression is an uninitialized value, analyzer warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I'm getting the following analyzer warning on this line...

```
if ([datStartDate compare:now] == NSOrderedDescending) {

Receiver in message expression is an uninitialized value
```

The line of code occurs in the middle of an IBAction.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the entire IBAction method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand the disclosure triangle next to the error (in the error navigator on the left side), it'll show you the exact code path that leads to a situation where the value is not initialized.

You may think "But, analyzer, really, that can *never* happen.".   While that may be true, you are creating an assumption in your code that may not hold true in the future due to bug or intentional change.   That increases the fragility of your codebase and will lead to maintenance headaches.

Fix the code such that it is explicit and remove the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one code path that can lead to this line with `datStartDate` still being uninitialized. That means you have never assigned an object to `datStartDate`, not even `nil`.